# Speed up video by ffmpeg did not reduce file size

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm following

Speeding up playback speed
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

However, when I speed up my playback speed by 1.5, I'd anticipate a reduce of the video's size on par with/about the same level, yet, this is what I got:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 me me 10000000 2021-10-10 16:56 original_video.mp4*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 me me 10060896 2022-01-02 16:27 speed_up_output.mkv*
```

I.e., the file size is even bigger.

Is it possible to speed up playback and reduce of the video's size to somewhat same degree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the commands mentioned in that link change the *playback* speed. In order to reduce the number of frames, you do not necessarily need to change playback speed.

The minterpolate filter can reduce the number of frames, but it is a rather lossy process.
You could drop every other frame, but most people notice frame-rates below 24 fps.

Reducing the number of frames will reduce the amount of data. For *uncompressed* videos, you can expect a linear correlation.
[This article](https://larryjordan.com/articles/how-changing-frame-rate-affects-file-size/) includes some examples. Please note the graphs are crap as the x-tics are not evenly distributed.

In most end-user scenarios, *compressed* videos are used. H264 is a wide-spread compressor. It uses differential aka. [predicted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types) frames. Dropping frames will interfere with the optical flow detection, making the video harder to compress (provided you want to maintain the same per-frame quality). For this reason, reducing the frame-rate will yield a less-than-linear reduction of file-size. Related: https://superuser.com/questions/283515/video-encoding-how-much-does-the-video-file-size-increase-with-fps

I just tried it using ffmpeg's decimate filter:

```
ffmpeg -i raw_footage.ts -an -c:v libx264 -crf 21 30fps.mkv
ffmpeg -i 30fps.mkv -filter:v decimate=cycle=2 -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -t 30 15fps.mkv
```

File-sizes:

- 30fps.mkv 9,4M
- 15fps.mkv 8,2M

With a reduced frame-rate, the video is awfully jumpy and hard to look at. Totally butchered, in my opinion. Yet the file-size has only been reduced by 12 %. Not a good deal.

For most use-cases, it is way easier to keep the number of frames and reduce the image quality per-frame.

```
ffmpeg -i original_video.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 31 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

`crf` is a quality setting. A higher number means "compress more".

Depending on what you are doing, switching to a higher [profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Profiles) can also help. Reducing the geometric resolution also helps. You may use a better compressor like libx265, if available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I _do_ want to increase playback speed though, that's my #1 goal. The question was how to drop file size accordingly.

Comment: You cannot expect much in terms of file-size reduction. I extended my answer with an explanation.

Comment: Loud and clear. Thanks!